# How to make a search form?

Tags: search, forms

I'm taking my first steps in wordpress, pretty newbie. and I find that I want to make a search form with its own styles and a little javascript to redimension. So I do not know how I should proceed in several ways.

- Is it better to use the get_search_form () method, inspect and change their styles? like for example the search-field class or for html5 searchform?
  OR
  Is it better to make my own form from scratch if it is going to have (many) changes?
- In the case that it is better to use get_search_form (), I inspect and change the styles directly? or do I support html5 and change the styles of these? Or is there a way to embed additional classes to the said form?
- in the case that it is better to make my own form as I do so that wordpress detects it as a search form? or that failing to do the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you code `get_search_form()` WP search searchform.php in your theme root and print all inside that file.
And you can create searchform.php inside your theme root and insert this:

```
    <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
            <button></button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

That basic search form.
Then code `<?php get_search_form() ?>` where you want this form in your theme. You can add your own class or ID inside that form and change what you want. Also I put [link for couple notes about search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/#user-contributed-notes)